# How to import r.in.gdal from WCS (only region extent)

Tags: gdal, grass-gis, wcs

**Can I import WCS-Data only for the current region by `r.in.gdal`?**

I tried to import raster data from my WCS into GRASS GIS, using r.in.gdal as proposed in 
http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Global_datasets#OGC_WCS_-_Albedo_example .

Then I added an BBOX definition to the XML file as follows:

```
<WCS_GDAL>
<ServiceURL>http://localhost/mywcs?</ServiceURL>
<CoverageName>blw.eros_z</CoverageName>
<Timeout>90</Timeout>
<GetCoverageExtra>&BBOX=2596000,1181000,2597500,1182500</GetCoverageExtra>
</WCS_GDAL>
```

However, r.in.gdal just starts to load the whole dataset in 2MB chunks, ignoring my BBOX argument. r.in.gdal also lacks a `-r` option, what would be even better.

Altough, when I try to manually download my region extent with a browser, it works well and I get the wanted GeoTiff file for my extent:

```
http://localhost/mywcs?SERVICE=WCS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCoverage&coverage=blw.eros_z&FORMAT=image/tiff&CRS=EPSG:2056&BBOX=2596000,1181000,2597500,1182500&RESX=2&RESY=2
```

Background: I have large raster files (12 x 1 GB, erosion risk data of CH http://s.geo.admin.ch/bb8ef7c7f) with overlapping areas. Instead of patching everything together with r.patch (did work well for 2 rasters, less for >10...), I want to get only the area of interest per WCS (Mapserver 6.4.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It perhaps depends more on the server than GDAL (BTW: you can also use [r.external](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.external.html) in order to register the external data source).

Please collect your findings on the new Wiki page: http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/WCS